# Issue when using array_merge to merge multiple arrays into a single one

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Before I jump into the code  let me display the current representation of the array hierarchy

```
Array
(
    [Details] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [itemId] => 9999
                            [itemName] => test
                            [itemPrice] => 0.00
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [itemId] => 10
                            [itemName] => yest
                            [itemPrice] => 12
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

My desired outcome is slightly different

```
Array
(
    [Details] => Array
        (
            
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [itemId] => 9999
                            [itemName] => test
                            [itemPrice] => 0.00
                        )

                

            
                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [itemId] => 10
                            [itemName] => yest
                            [itemPrice] => 12
                        )

                )

        )
)
```

To my understanding it looks like the problem is because my code generate a new array inside of each for eachloop. I tried using Array_merge to try and have them in a single array yet it turned out that it only returned a single stack of elements.

Would really appreciate if someone can help me identify my mistake.

My code

```
public function getData($list)
    {
        
        $itemDetails= array();

        foreach ($listas $Item) {

            $query = $this->db->get_where('items_table', array('Name' => $Item));

            $queryResult = $query->result();
            $itemDetails[] = $queryResult;

            $result = array_merge($itemDetails,$queryResult);

            //$temp = array_merge($toppingDetails,$queryResult);



            
        }

        return array('Details'=>$itemDetails);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't assign to `$itemDetails[]`. Use `array_merge()` there.

```
public function getData($list)
{
    $itemDetails= array();

    foreach ($listas $Item) {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('items_table', array('Name' => $Item));
        $queryResult = $query->result();
        $itemDetails = array_merge($itemDetails, $queryResult);
    }

    return array('Details' => $itemDetails);
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply.  So where does this Details array and $queryResult get connected ?

Comment: Just use this with the array you showed at the beginning of the question.

Comment: I assumed that all elements of the array just have one nested element.